# FInding the columns count with mutliple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
    ID PID TID CID DID IsTrue
    1   43  1   2   621  0
    2   43  1   2   621  1
    3   45  2   3   621  1
    4   46  2   3   621  0
```

and I need to find the count of PID,CID and with the where condition DID=621 along with the other fields.
how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: look on google  `group by` and use it

Comment: Need to find the count on both the columns and am not getting the right answer

Comment: What answer are you getting? Show us your query. Our mind readers are malfunctioning, lately.

Comment: Count of pid and cid will be same. Correct me if I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select count(pid) from table where did = 121 group by pid.